# How to interact with elements when rollover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an expandable rollover but to interact with elements inside. So what I have here is an expandable div and when is expanded another div is shown "x". What I want is when I click on #wrap to go on google and when I click on #button to go on yahoo. How you can see, now if I am over "x" I am going out of #wrap area and going as mouseout. Any idea how to fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/Ln6q9q9b/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#wrap").hover(
    //on mouseover
    function() {
      $(this).animate({height: '+=250'}, 'slow');
      $('#button').css('display', 'block');
      expanded = true;
      console.log("expanded is " + expanded);
    },
    //on mouseout
    function() {
      $(this).animate({height: '-=250px'}, 'slow');
      $("#button").hide();
      expanded = false;
      console.log("expanded is " + expanded);
    }
  );
  $('#wrap').on('click', function(){
    window.open('http://google.com', 'click', 'window settings');
    return false;
    console.log('click');
  });
  if(expanded = true){
    $("#button").on('click', function(){
        window.open('http://yahoo.com', 'click', 'window settings');
        return false;
      });
  };

});
</script> 

<style type="text/css">
#wrap{
  width: 900px;
  height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: black;
}
#button{
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 10;
  top: 10;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
</div>
<div id="button">X</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `if(expanded = true){` should presumably  be `if(expanded === true){` or even just `if (expanded) `.

Comment: Yes, it should simply be `if(expanded)` -- also, you've commented `//on mouseout` and `//on mouseover` which is not what jQuery's .hover() method does. You should read up on it here: https://api.jquery.com/hover/ -- But it appears you are quite far from the result you're seeking. Do want the menu to animate up and down constantly? Seems like a nightmare UX to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the button inside `wrap`.

And give `position: relative;` to `wrap.`

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/Ln6q9q9b/1/

Comment: while this would solve the problem OP describes, it would create another problem whereby clicking the #button would bubble up to the #wrap. The action for the click event on the #button would need to have `function(e){e.stopPropagation(); [and the existing js]  }`

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, but take a look at [relatedTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/).

> For mouseout, indicates the element being entered; for mouseover,
>   indicates the element being exited.

To your `mouseout` listener you could add

```
function (evt) {
    if(evt.relatedTarget.id === "button") return;
    $(this).animate({height: '-=250px'}, 'slow');
    //etc;
}
```

The following seems to work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var expanded = false;
  $("#wrap").hover(
    //on mouseover
    function() {
      if (expanded) { return; }
      $(this).animate({height: '+=250'}, 'slow');
      $('#button').css('display', 'block');
      expanded = true;
      console.log("expanded is " + expanded);
    },
    //on mouseout
    function(evt) {
      if (evt.relatedTarget.id === "button") { return; }
      $(this).animate({height: '-=250px'}, 'slow');
      $("#button").hide();
      expanded = false;
      console.log("expanded is " + expanded);
    }
  );
  $('#wrap').on('click', function(){
    window.open('http://google.com', 'click', 'window settings');
    return false;
    console.log('click');
  });
  $("#button").on('click', function(evt){
      window.open('http://yahoo.com', 'click', 'window settings');
      return false;
  });
});
```

I've added `if (expanded) { return; }` to the mouseover listener too, and removed the `if (expanded = true)` check entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, all you need to do is put the #button inside the #wrap div.

```
<div id="wrap"><div id="button">X</div></div>
```

Leave the rest the same and it seems to work as you want.